# Correct syntax for nmap

Tags: ip

I am trying to use nmaps os fingerprint or what ever the hell it is called.. So i put it`sudo nmap -o 208.80.125.4` (and i have used a lot of other IPs.. It always works correctly without the -o except there is no OS detection...  though it says the host doesn't exist if I use the -o. Anyone know what I am doing incorrectly? I'm am probably being an idiot but feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So I just was being an idiot. Capital O.. Sorry for any wasted time..

Comment: Be sure to use the last version you can get. Normally the signatures of OSes are more up to date.